# In wso2 identity server 5.9.0 is it possible to restrict an SP authentication to a single user store?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've installed wso2 identity server 5.9.0 on OEL 7.6 with jdk 11.0.6. I've configured an SP for OpenID Connect based authentication - client is Oracle HTTP Server with mod_auth_oidc proxying requests to an app on weblogic server. I've created a secondary user store exclusively for my SP's users and I'd like to restrict SP authentication using only that secondary user store (without using a domain prefix for the login username) but am unable to find any options / info specifically for that. I would have more secondary user stores for other SP apps as well and they may have users with the same usernames. I've seen a post that talks about using XACML to implement a user-store or role restricted authorization policy - would this be the recommended approach for such a requirement or is there another easier/better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XACML policies as well. But in 5.9.0, you can use an adaptive authentication [script](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-user-store-based-adaptive-authentication/) to control access for specific user store.

The above-linked Scenarios is to step up if the user is from a specific user store. In your case, you don't need you can use [sendError](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#senderrorurlparameters) function if the user is from other user stores.

This is a sample script

```
var allowedUserstores = ['EMPLOYEES', 'CONTRACTORS'];

var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
            // Extracting user store domain of authenticated subject from the first step
            var userStoreDomain = context.currentKnownSubject.userStoreDomain;
            if (userStoresToStepUp.indexOf(userStoreDomain) < 0) {
                sendError('http://www.example.com/error',{'errorcode':'000403','errorMsg':'You are not allowed to login to this app.'});
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Senthalan, I'd seen the doc you mentioned but wasnt sure if a min of 2 steps were mandatory. Thanks. Will try and post on how it goes. Is this the only option to restrict SP authn to a user store? Does authn in wso2is otherwise ALWAYS look at all user stores? If i add more SPs, would it be required for me to enable multitenancy and add new tenants or would my current (and your suggested) approach suffice (add new SP and based on requirements & use adaptive authn to restrict to one or more user stores)? Any refs to docs on wso2is tenants, domains, user stores etc. would  be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Senthalan,    
I couldnt get the code to work.    
Just to check if adaptive authn is indeed happening, I put the below code instead but still authn succeeds.    
Could you please advise what I may be doing wrong?  
  
`var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) {
                sendError('http://aaa.bbb.com',{'errorcode':'000999','errorMsg':'You are not allowed to login to this app.'});
        }
    });
};`

Comment: Hi Senthalan, Sorry but I was testing using curl and password grant type to test which kept returning an access code (some issues with SP setup). When tested via SP, i can see that the adaptive authn script in effect. Now need to test this use case and see it working - will post updates of its progress.

Comment: Yes.  Password grant flow will not invoke the adaptive or XAMCL policy. You need to try  flows which prompt login page

Answer (score 0):

You can use XACML for fine-grained access control. For the authentication flow,

- Publish a XACML policy via management cosole that can validate the user attributes and userstore and return whether user can be authenticated to access the resource.
- You can follow this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-access-control-policy-for-a-service-provider/) to configure Access Control Policy for a Service Provider.

A sample XACML policy to authenticate the users based on userstore is given below

```xml
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="authn_dynamic_userstore_based_policy_template" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>This policy template provides ability to authorize users to a given service provider(defined by SP_NAME) in the authentication flow based on the userstore of the user. Users who are in the userstore,will be allowed any others will be denied.</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">travelocity.com</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/sp/sp-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/sp" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">authenticate</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action/action-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="permit_by_userstore">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">PRIMARY</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/user/user-store-domain" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/user" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">carbon.super</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/user/user-tenant-domain" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/user" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny_others"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

Comment: Hi Piraveena, Thanks for the answer but wouldnt the ACL only kick in AFTER the authentication process itself, which may have happened successfully using user creds from any of the wso2is user stores. I was wondering if the authentication process itself may be restricted to a specifc user store. Please let me know if I'm not clear in what I'm asking, since this is the first time for me with using wso2is (have worked on Oracle OAM before).

Comment: Did you configure "Enable Authorization" in the SP level by following this doc? and published the policy to PDP?

Comment: Hi Piraveena, Oh no, I havent yet started trying out what you suggested - just wanted to better understand the use case for using ACLs. Could you please clarify the following for me - I would like for the user to be authenticated against a single user store **without** using a domain/userstore prefix - if the same username (and password) appears in 2 user stores and the first one (dont know what order is followed by wso2is) is used to successfully authenticate the user while the second one is the only one allowed by the ACL, would the user never be able to login?